# INSERTING and UPDATING SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How to INSERT data in a table that has a forgien key ? 
i tried doing this

```
INSERT INTO City (name, country, population) VALUES ("NewZelans", "Auckland", "80000");
```

however it gave me an error

`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (stu_nall596_compsci_280_c_s2_2014.city, CONSTRAINT city_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES Country (id))`

and in term of updating a field, how to do that?

Comment: Make sure `NewZelans` is in the `country` table

Comment: do you have a typo, and mean NewZealand instead of NewZelans

Comment: I would expect something in the line `VALUES ('Auckland', 217, 80000)`, first the name of the city, then the ID of New Zealand of your country table and then the population. The ID and the population are integers and need no quotes (MySQL permits them, I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that "NewZelans" is not a city, and "Auckland" is a city and not a country, if you wanted your insert to succeed, you would need to insert a row into `Country` with a corresponding `id` of `"Auckland"` before the constraint will allow you to insert a new row into `City` table for a city of that country.

I don't know what your schema looks like, but here's a rough example;

```
INSERT INTO Country (id, name) VALUES (123, 'New Zealand');

INSERT INTO City (name, country, population) VALUES ('Auckland', 123, 80000);
```

See, the `id` of `123` must exist in the `Country` table before I can reference it in the `City` table.

Comment: What you mean by inserting a row into Counrty table? 
can you give me a code example ?

Comment: Sweet, that worked, what about updating ? how could i do that.. if we want to update the population to 2000 ?